# How to check Exists records by some fields - Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Before I insert a new product, I want to check whether that value already exists in the database. I have some values in some fields that can be null and false.

I created method like this :

```
public bool IsExists(Guid warrantyId, bool hasColor, Guid? colorId, bool hasSize, Guid? sizeId)
{
    return _products.Any(row => (hasColor && row.ColorId.Value == colorId.Value) && (hasSize && row.SizeId.Value == sizeId.Value) && row.WarrantyId == warrantyId);
}
```

but it always returns `false`.

When I remove this part

```
row.WarrantyId == warrantyId
```

it works fine. I don't know how can check it .

here is some data in my database:

[image]

I passed this Item to method:

```
warrantyId:F1F2D639-22AF-618A-7422-4122BB38D545

hascolor:true , ColorId: 47f3d639-18de-5d26-91f7-0cd4465a161a

HasSize:false and SizeId:null
```

its return false.

I Rewrite Method like this ,and work fine .

```
 public bool IsExists(Guid warrantyId, bool hasColor, Guid? colorId, bool hasSize, Guid? sizeId)
    {
       var result = _products.Where(row => row.WarrantyId == warrantyId).AsQueryable();
       if (hasColor)
           result = result.Where(row => row.ColorId.Value == colorId.Value).AsQueryable();
       else
           result = result.Where(row=>row.HasColor==false).AsQueryable();
       if (hasSize)
           result = result.Where(row => row.SizeId.Value == sizeId.Value).AsQueryable();
       else
           result = result.Where(row => row.HasSize == false).AsQueryable() ;

        return result.Any();

    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to match? Show an example of a database row which your expect to return `true` and the values in your parameters

Comment: @StephenMuecke sorry I debug my code and its wrong , do you have any idea?

Comment: Cant possibly help unless you give an example of the data your expecting to return `true`

Comment: @UthmanRahimi As Stephen said it would help if you provide some data. Have you tried these combinations and what are the results 1.) _products.Any(row => row.WarrantyId == warrantyId); 2.) _products.Any(row => row.WarrantyId == warrantyId && (hasColor && row.ColorId.Value == colorId.Value)); 3.) _products.Any(row => row.WarrantyId == warrantyId && (hasSize && row.SizeId.Value == sizeId.Value));

Comment: @StephenMuecke Updated question , please see it

Comment: `hasSize` is `false` so it will always return false. Best guess is you mean `(row.HasColor == hasColor && row.ColorId.Value == colorId.Value)` (ditto for `HasSize`). But in any case, there are no rows that match that data so of course it will return `false`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I changed , but when one of `HasSize` or `HasColor` = `false ` it always return `False`

Comment: But there are no rows that match what your data. Why would you expect it to return `true`?

Comment: I used `&&` in my Query and if one of them equals to `False` result =`False` becuase operattor `&&`  when return True if all operand equals True. and when one of the `hasColor` and `HasSize` =`false` , result =`false`

Answer (score 1):

Like Stephen Muecke pointed in the comment, your database does not have the row with what you are looking for. Also, if I am not mistaken `row.SizeId.Value == sizeId.Value` will still return true in case `row.SizeId.Value` in the database is `NULL` and `sizeId.Value` is concrete value (not null).

There is a better way to check existence based on multiple columns in case when you know that you will perform a lot of such searches. However, this method requires table alteration. You need to introduce new column `EntryHash` which is calculated hash of values from other columns. Make it `Unique` if you need to have only unique set of values. If not, make an index on it anyway. The idea is that your query will be performed over single column only, which will be faster. Here is proposed method to calculate hash (pay attention to nullified values).

```
public static string CreateEntryHash(Guid warrantyId, bool hasColor, Guid? colorId, bool hasSize, Guid? sizeId)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append(warrantyId);
    sb.Append(hasColor);
    sb.Append(colorId == null ? "null" : colorId.ToString());
    sb.Append(hasSize);
    sb.Append(sizeId == null ? "null" : sizeId.ToString());

    var hash = GetMd5Hash(sb.ToString());

    return hash;
}

public static string GetMd5Hash(string input)
{
    StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    using (MD5 md5Hash = MD5.Create())
    {
        byte[] data = md5Hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input));
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            sBuilder.Append(data[i].ToString("x2"));
        }
    }

    return sBuilder.ToString();
}

public bool IsExists(Guid warrantyId, bool hasColor, Guid? colorId, bool hasSize, Guid? sizeId)
{
    var hash = CreateEntryHash(warrantyId, hasColor, colorId, hasSize, sizeId);
    return _products.Any(p => p.EntryHash == hash);
}
```